# Store data relationships on a file for very fast read?

Tags: data-structures

I am tasked with finding a solution to the following real word problem and I am really puzzled on how I can solve it.

We have 100 million numbers and 1 billion arrays of numbers (each array can hold up to 1.000 unique numbers).

We pick 1.000 random numbers. We are trying to find the IDs of arrays containing more than 1 of our 1.000 numbers. If there are more than 10.000 such arrays we need the 1st 10.000 only.

In a file for each number we store the IDs of arrays that number appears on. We can solve the problem by reading all the array IDs for every number and processing them. But those IDs are 8 bytes each, so we need to read 8*1 billion = 8GB of data per number if our number appears on every array. If we take the worse case scenario we need to read from the HDD 8GB*1.000 = 8TB. This takes days, not 1 second.

**Question**: How can I do this in 1 second (or a few seconds) instead of days?

**Hint**: Seems like my problem is similar to problems the search engines face. I have no experience on that field but someone who has can be really helpful here.

Comment: That's not how this site works. You have to [ask a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Comment: @ Dour High Arch: Thanks, my question is how to do this job in 1 second instead of days.

Comment: Definitely don't do it in arrays. Or on a hard drive. Your best bet probably involves databases.

Comment: @ Shadowen: I think there will be huge perfomance issues if I store so many records...

Comment: I thought storing was a foregone conclusion? Where else would you get the numbers from?

Comment: Your description is unclear.  If the domain is 100M numbers, each number would be held in an average of 10,000 arrays (with 1B arrays @ 1,000 entries each).  If you have a file for each number with array IDs, those files would be an average of 8 bytes * 10000 or 80k bytes.  Per number, that's all you have to read (on average).

Comment: Do you want to repeatedly get 1000 random numbers (and find the 'matching' arrays) while your arrays don't change or do you get a new set of arrays and numbers each time? Is this an interview or homework problem, or a real-world problem? If you posted all the information you have from the homework or interview question, we'd know there isn't more information (unless you go ask your lecturer things, which is possible), for a real-world problem, there could always be something else to find out, and you generally deal with real-world space and time constraints, which are important to specify.

Comment: @Dukeling: It's a real word problem, I am working for a startup and my Boss asked me to awnser if solving the above is possible. We never add new data, so you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: @John Pirie: I updated the question to make it a bit more clear. The average case is not bad but the worst case is so bad that takes days. We are trying to fix that.